# Access substring in a dataframe column to create a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 1)), columns=list('A'))
df.insert(0, 'n', ['this-text in presence 20-30%, and another string','id XDTV/HGF, publication',
                   'this-text, 37$degree','this-text K0.5, coefficient 0.007',' '])

>>> df
    n                                                 A
0   this-text in presence 20-30%, and another string  2
1   id XDTV/HGF, publication                          1
2   this-text, 37$degree                              4
3   coefficient 0.007,this-text K0.5                  1
4                                                     2
```

I'd like to create a new column

```
>>> df
    new       A
0   this-text 2
1             1
2   this-text 4
3   this-text 1
4             2
```

I could save the column `n` in a list and check if each item of the list contains the substring `this-text`. But I'd like to know if there are better ways of doing this.
Suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `str.findall` or `extract`

```
df['new']=df.n.str.findall('this-text').str[0] 
#df.n.str.extract('(this-text)')[0]

df
Out[373]: 
                                                  n  A        new
0  this-text in presence 20-30%, and another string  7  this-text
1                          id XDTV/HGF, publication  4        NaN
2                              this-text, 37$degree  6  this-text
3                 this-text K0.5, coefficient 0.007  0  this-text
4                                                    7        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. On my real data I get an error `None type object not subscriptable`, I will check the column data and post you here for further suggestions.